# Some questions about my 4TB external drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

I plugged in my 4TB external HDD (Which I have stored for quite a while now) today and Windows detected it instantly without any problems...

Then I launched Seatools to check the drive health and it got stuck at this window for more than 4 minutes and then it was not responding...so I had to end the Seatools process from task manager:

Seatools screenshot

[image: Seatools Window]

My first question: Can this cause disk corruption ?

I launched Seatools again afterwards but this time I waited a bit longer and It worked...I launched Crystal Disk info and it got stuck as well but after waiting for sometime, it also worked...

My second question: Why is it that Seatools and CrystalDiskInfo cannot detect the drive instantly ? Is there a problem with the disk ?

I ran a Short Generic and Short drive self test and both tests passed...

EDIT: Now Crystaldiskinfo detects the disk right away....I launched CrystalDiskInfo and HDDscan both twice and they didn't get stuck for 4+ minutes....they ran smoothly this time....weird

Here is the SMART report:

[image: SMART Report]

Comment: Without logs from both of those programs we won't be able to tell you the reason they took so long to detect your drive.

Comment: How do i find the log ?

Comment: "Is there a problem with the disk ? Most likely. Read the SMART data for that drive.

Comment: Can you give any additional information about the drive?